# A game in combinatorial game theory

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I have been reading the Winning Ways, the bible (?) of Combinatorial Game Theory.

I tried to calculate some games of the form {L|R}. But it is not easy to me.

For example, I don't know what {$\uparrow$,$\ast$ | $\downarrow$,$\ast$} is.

The game, say $G$, is fuzzy and $G+G=0$.

So I thought that the game might be $\ast$.

But $G+\ast$ is still fuzzy. Moreover $G+*n ~||~ 0$. Thus $G$ is not an impartial game.

I think $G$ can be simplified to the comibination of several symbols like $\ast$ or nimbers. But I have no idea.

Teach me, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Games $H$ such that $H=\{G_L|-G_L\}$ form a closed set under addition, satisfy $H+H=0$, and must be either equal to $0$ or fuzzy with $0$.  Some of these are *nimbers*: $*=\{0|0\}, *2=\{0,*|0,*\}$, etc.  Those that are not nimbers and not zero seem to be typically written as $\pm(G_L)$, such as $\pm 1 = \{1|-1\}$, so your game is $$G=\{\uparrow, * \big\vert\downarrow,*\} = \pm(\uparrow,*).$$  Your game and the result of adding $*$ to it,
$$G+* = \pm(0,\uparrow*),$$
are two of the simpler such games, with birthday equal to $3$.  They satisfy
$$
\downarrow*\text{}<G<\text{}\uparrow*\qquad\text{and}\qquad\downarrow\text{}< G+*<\quad\uparrow,
$$
giving an idea of how "unfuzzy" they are; but $G$ is fuzzy with $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$.  (Note that $*$ behaves exactly the same as $G$ in all these particulars $-$ it is fuzzy with $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$, strictly between $\uparrow*$ and $\downarrow*$, and becomes between $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ after adding $*$ to it.)

Comment: Thank you for your helful comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can check that $G$ has no dominated or reversible options (this is easy once you've checked that $\uparrow*$, $G$, and $G + *$ are all fuzzy), so the form you've given is already the canonical form.  Being in canonical form doesn't mean it couldn't be a *sum* of simpler objects, though.

However, in this case, $G$ doesn't simplify to any sum of ups, downs, or nimbers.  Two (or more) ups plus a nimber is positive, whereas $G$ is not.  A single up is also positive.  The game $\uparrow *n$, if $n>1$, is also positive.  The game $\uparrow *$ is fuzzy, but 2 of them added together give $\uparrow \uparrow$ which is positive whereas $G+G=0$.

Comment: I see. Thank you, Ted.
Is there any symbol for this game $G$?

Comment: I don't know of any symbol for it.  The software [CGSuite](http://cgsuite.sourceforge.net/) for studying combinatorial games, doesn't simplify it any further.

Comment: Thank you for your information about CGSuite.